# Error show product on safari (-webkit-flex), Help me reslove?

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress, safari

**Code css :**

```
.md_flexbox .view-grid .products {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: wrap;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

It shows all products but just one column
[display: -webkit-flex (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfksz.png)

**code css :**

```
.md_flexbox .view-grid .products {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: wrap;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

It shows 2 products on one row, but my category has 15 products.
[display: -webkit-box (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czxB2.png)

How can I resolve it? I need all your help.